Creating on demand discount codes with Shopify Automation
Background
I am working with Shopify's automation system. I am creating a cart abandonment automation, to email the customer with discount offers to complete the transaction. Shopify's automation system is similar to ladder code, in that it is graphical, it is conditional programming, and focuses on work-flows. Discounts can be created and given to the customer as a code, but not on demand, and not one time use.
What I have researched
Shopify's automation system does have documentation, with explanations for syntax. Nothing about the creation of discount codes on demand is mentioned, and questions I found in the community are not answered.
Questions about APIs on StackExchange are about how to use the API in a programming language such as java and javascript. I am by order limited to using the built in automation system, but the purchase of apps can be allowed, though what is available in the email app and default/free apps are preferred.
I do not believe there is an answer available to me already out there.
What I want to do
I want to create a discount code when the abandoned cart email is sent, and a way to delete the code once used, or a certain amount of time has passed, or another discount code has been created and sent to the same customer.
Limitation
I am by order limited to the available applications on Shoppify, so writing my own solution is not an answer, and this is not a question about developing my own software.

I am reviewing deleted closed questions.  I was the one who closed this so I'm adding it to the reopen-review queue to allow the community a chance to do its own review to decide if it should remain closed or be reopened.  Notes: OP edited the Q i2 months after closure to focus it away from web development.  They may be looking for a module/software recommendation (free or paid) instead.
